# Which namespace is used to uniquely identify a web service?

Tags: wcf, xml-namespaces

Each XML web service should use a unique namespace so that client applications can distinguish it from other services on the web. Which namespace is used to identify a service: one set via `ServiceContractAttribute.Namespace` or via `ServiceBehaviorAttribute.Namespace` or...? My guess would be one set via  `ServiceBehaviorAttribute.Namespace`?!